# React-Native WebView Image with %2B char

Tags: amazon-s3, webview, android-webview, react-native

I'm trying to open a HTML content in a WebView on an React-Native Android Application, but, when this HTML contains an images with the source like this:

https://doohnow.s3-sa-east-1.amazonaws.com/636166093148167746/images%20(1).png?AWSAccessKeyId=AKIAI47DIW2SE7LA3C7A&Expires=1808593725&Signature=3HjMbOX0%2Bk0H/kNQuhpKnXSW82M=

The image do not load.

After a long time testing I've figure out that the problem is with the %2B char, that is equal to '+' (plus sign) in the url. But both, + and %2B do not load the image. Just this char.

Someone can help me please? I try everything, but anything works!

A temporary workaroud is to generate another url every time that the url contains this char, but I think that this is not the best solution.

**UPDATE**

To be more clear, this link that I provide works fine in the web browser, but no inside the react-native webview. If I put this link in a img source and open in browser, the image load just fine, but if I put the same HTML inside the webview, the image do not load.

Comment: S3 has a known issue with improper handling of `+`... it is a bug that has been there for 10+ years, so it can't be fixed by S3... but it can be solved -- you just have to do it wrong in the same way that S3 does.  Please provide an example of a link that does not work -- the link in the question works fine.  If you can provide a broken link, I can probably pinpoint the exact nature of the error for you... it could be on the upload side or the download side.

Comment: This link works just if you open in the webbrowser but not inside my react-native app webview. This is the problem that I want to solve. Sorry if I was not clear in my question. If I put this link in a img source, the same HTML code works on browser, but not inside the webview. I'll edt my question to be more clear. Tks anyway.

Comment: You said the issue was `%2B` but this url has `%20`.

Comment: yes, but i test urls with only %20 or others chars like this and it works, just with %2B the problem hapens.